# Error: Unrolling requires a fixed number of timesteps - LSTM - recurrent dropout

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, unroll

I am working with an **LSTM model** on time series data. My idea is to add **recurrent dropout** to the LSTM layer to mitigate overfitting. By default, Keras uses a cuDNN kernel to optimize training. According to the official Keras documentation, recurrent_dropout is not compatible with cuDNN. One of the creators of Keras, Francois Chollet, recommends setting unroll = True in the LSTM layer to optimally run training with the previously mentioned dropout.

The model I am working with is as follows:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(sequence_length, raw_data.shape[-1]))
x = layers.LSTM(32, recurrent_dropout = 0.25, unroll=True)(inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)  # Avoid exploding gradient
outputs = layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("basic_lstm6.tf",
                                    save_best_only=True)
]

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=val_dataset_except_last,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

When training starts, I get the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_7 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.

Epoch 1/20

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-caf68cfbe99f> in <cell line: 13>()
     11 
     12 model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
---> 13 history = model.fit(
     14   train_dataset,
     15   epochs=20,

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

 ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lstm_7' (type LSTM).
    
    Unrolling requires a fixed number of timesteps.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'lstm_7' (type LSTM):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 2), dtype=float32)
      • mask=None
      • training=True
      • initial_state=None
```

The "train_dataset" dataset is calculated as follows:

```
raw_data = merged_df[['VIX', 'Bid price']].to_numpy()
num_train_samples = int(0.5 * len(raw_data))
num_val_samples = int(0.25 * len(raw_data))
num_test_samples = len(raw_data) - num_train_samples - num_val_samples


from tensorflow import keras

sampling_rate = 2 # 
sequence_length = 40 
delay = sampling_rate * (sequence_length + 24 - 1)
batch_size = 100


train_dataset = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  raw_data[:-delay],
  targets=bid_prices[delay:],
  sampling_rate=sampling_rate,
  sequence_length=sequence_length,
  shuffle=True, 
  batch_size=batch_size,
  start_index=0,
  end_index=num_train_samples)

val_dataset = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  raw_data[:-delay],
  targets=bid_prices[delay:],
  sampling_rate=sampling_rate,
  sequence_length=sequence_length,
  shuffle=True,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  start_index=num_train_samples,
  end_index=num_train_samples + num_val_samples)

test_dataset = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  raw_data[:-delay],
  targets=bid_prices[delay:],
  sampling_rate=sampling_rate,
  sequence_length=sequence_length,
  shuffle=True,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  start_index=num_train_samples + num_val_samples)
```

I used timeserie_dataset_from_array() and when I print the shape of a batch, for example, from train_dataset, it returns the shape: samples shape: (100, 40, 2) targets shape: (100)

The code is similar to the one in the book "Deep Learning with Python, Second Edition" by Francois Chollet (Chapter 10). You can find the code on his GitHub:  https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter10_dl-for-timeseries.ipynb

Comment: Same issue on my end:
`inputs = keras.Input(shape=(sequence_length, raw_data.shape[-1]))` returns `input.shape` = `[None, 120, 14]`, whereas in the error similar to what you posted, it says `Call arguments received by layer 'lstm_1' (type LSTM):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 14), dtype=float32)`

I don't understand the discrepancy between (None, 120, 14) and (None, None, 14) for the inputs passed into the LSTM.